# How to check if time is not between two time entries within select

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two columns in PostgreSQL that store time values (H:M:S) and I use SQLAlchemy.
How can I make a select using SQLAlchemy for values that are not between the two values?

Example 1:

- current time in the interrogation = 10:00:01
- start_time = 16:00:12
- end_time = 22:00:00
  Return the value because is outside of this time interval

2:

- current time = 10:00:01
- start_time = 07:00:12
- end_time = 22:00:00
  Return nothing because is within this interval.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN start_time <= current_time and end_time >= current_time
         THEN current_time
         ELSE NULL :: time
       END 
  FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the negation operator [NOT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-logical.html) with [BETWEEN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html).

```
select '10:00:01'::time not between '16:00:12'::time and '22:00:00'::time;
 ?column? 
----------
 t

 select '10:00:01'::time not between '07:00:12'::time and '22:00:00'::time;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
```

To select from the table you would want something like:

```
select time_col from the_table where time_col not between '16:00:12'::time and '22:00:00'::time;

--or

select time_col from the_table where time_col not between '07:00:12' and '22:00:00'::time;
```

As to SQLAlchemy see [Between](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.between):

> from sqlalchemy import between

> stmt = select(users_table).where(between(users_table.c.id, 5, 7))

and I believe to negate that it would be something like:

`select(users_table).where(~between(users_table.c.id, 5, 7))`